# Pay Dialog not Appearing

Tags: facebook, sdk, dialog, payment

I'm trying to launch the Pay Dialog to enable purchasing of in game currency in our app. However, no matter what I try, the dialog does not appear, no error message or anything.

I'll just run through a list of all the things that I've tried to root the problem out.

1. If I run the app from our webpage, a popup appears with API Error Code: 1151. If run within Facebook, this pop up does not appear, nothing appears.
2. The Payments Callback URL has been set up, as has the server side code. This has been tested manually, but our logs show no calls from facebook itself.
3. I have tried launching it from within our app in Actionscript, and also calling a JavaScript function, both behave the same.
4. I've tried buy_credits as well to try and rule out the callback (as this apparently does not require the callback to function), and this has the same issue.
5. I have just managed to successfully call it by setting up a direct URL call and pasting it into my browser, so that verifies the server side code is working.

At this stage, I'm wondering if it's a problem with Dialog display modes. Last week I set up app requests, and was unable to get the request dialog to show up in an iframe. It currently only works as a popup. It was exactly the same problem, no error message, just nothing would happen. Since the pay dialog uses the page display mode, perhaps there is a problem with that and the iframe display mode. I can't find anyone else with this problem however.

I don't believe it's a code issue anymore, as I've tried a ton of examples, and they all behave the same, including code taken straight from the Facebook developers page, as well as other users in Stack Overflow. I'll post it here just in case, but I'm sure it must be some kind of setting either in the app settings on facebook, or the index.html.

AS:

```
   order_info =
   {
      title:'Test Product',
      description:'Test product description',
      price:'123'
   };

   Facebook.ui(
      "pay.prompt",
      {order_info: order_info, purchase_type: "item"},
      payCallback);
```

JS:

```
function make_purchase()
{
    var obj = {
    method: 'pay',
    action: 'buy_item',
    order_info: {'item_id': '1a'},
    dev_purchase_params: {'oscif': true}
    };

    FB.ui(obj, js_callback);
}

var js_callback = function(data) 
{
    if (data['order_id']) {
    }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this. In case anyone wants to know, I am embedding the flash object of our game into the webpage with embedSWF, changing it so it's added with an Object tag solved the problem. I currently don't know why embedding it causes dialogs not to appear, but I'll post here again when I find out.